# Update Boolean Within UseState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Is there a way to initiate state to true, then change to false after x amount of time within `useState`?

Currently looks like this:

```
const [scrollDown, setScrollDown] = useState(true)

setTimeout(() => {
    setScrollDown(false)
  }, 2000)
```

Looking to do something like this, but syntax doesn't appear to be correct:

```
const [scrollDown, setScrollDown] = useState(() => {
   setScrollDown(true)
   setTimeout(() => {
    setScrollDown(false)
  }, 2000)
})
```

Trying this as well:

```
const [scrollDown, setScrollDown] = useState(true, () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setScrollDown(false)
    }, 1000)
  })
```

Comment: You can use `useEffect()`, to start your timeout when the component mounts, and then set the state to false

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons - I did try that initially but forgot to include that second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, using `useEffect` works best so I went with this solution. My issue initially was passing that second empty array arg:

```
const [scrollDown, setScrollDown] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setScrollDown(false)
    }, 1000)
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid both of the code snippets you mentioned are not correct. useStates expects the value but we're returning nothing. Also, we can't pass second argument to useState. Your best bet would be to utilize useEffect that runs on first render only. There you can place your timeout.